# Container error when creating channel during running fabcar (fabric-sample)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Getting up to speed with Hyperledger and trying to run through the Hyperledger-Fabric tutorial fabcar, but hitting an error every time that I try to create the channel in the startFabric.sh script.

Here's the error:

*Error response from daemon: Container 3640f4fca98aef120a2069292a3fc613954a0fbe7c625a31c2843ec643462 is not running*

Ran all the pre-requisites and the commands listed, cloned the latest fabric-samples, updated node, tried longer start times. But still have this error. If anyone knows where I am going wrong would really appreciate some help to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Perhaps worth mentioning that I am running on Windows 7 and using Docker Toolbox.

startFabric.sh output is shown below.

```
$ ./startFabric.sh node

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Stopping ca.example.com ... done
Stopping couchdb        ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing ca.example.com         ... done
Removing couchdb                ... done
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Creating ca.example.com      ... done
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
Error response from daemon: Container 4ebfce361f3e71dd2d678efca1dbf1853cc5387b491f706917b8c54013ec6a80 is not running
```

docker ps output:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CRED             STATUS              PORTS                                      AMES
2d93296f3cb1        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-entâ¦"   13nutes ago      Up 13 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcpcouchdb
6b8638d0ecaf        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-seâ¦"   13nutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                    ca.example.com
```

docker ps -a output:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
4ebfce361f3e        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        15 minutes ago      Exited (1) 15 minutes ago                                                peer0.org1.example.com
1187120cdcd0        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                15 minutes ago      Exited (1) 15 minutes ago                                                orderer.example.com
2d93296f3cb1        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-entâ¦"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes               4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb
6b8638d0ecaf        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-seâ¦"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes               0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                       ca.example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue was caused by the volume handoff from WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux - available on Windows 10) to Docker. Use Kitematic to view your docker containers (See screenshot below and note how the folder path is messed up). Click the container and go to "Settings" and "Volumes". Changing the volume manually made it run properly.

In my case, docker automatically is changing \c to C:
[image]

I was able to resolve it with this trick: https://superuser.com/questions/1195215/docker-client-on-wsl-creates-volume-path-problems/1203233
WSL mounts the windows drives at /mnt/ (so /mnt/c/  = C:). If we create a /c/ bind point, this allows Docker to properly interpret this as C:\

Here's the process:

Bind the drive and download fabric to your windows user directory by using the following set of commands (one at a time)

```
sudo mkdir /c

sudo mount --bind /mnt/c /c

cd /c/Users/YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME #(go to C:\Users to see what its called)

mkdir blockchain #(or whatever you want to call it)

cd blockchain

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-dev-servers.tar.gz

tar -xvf fabric-dev-servers.tar.gz

cd ~/fabric-dev-servers

export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv12

./downloadFabric.sh
```

Now you should be able to successfully run Fabric

```
./startFabric.sh
```

It may ask you to share C drive with docker. You should do so. You can check the volume mount points and containers in Kitematic, like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

- Remove all containers - docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
- Remove network - docker network prune
- Remove the chaincode image (if existing) - docker rmi  dev-peer0.org1.example.com
- Restart docker
- Run startFabric.sh again.

Hope help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried yours suggestions, but still have the same issue. The two container errors are listed below:$ docker logs peer0.org1.example.com
2018-07-02 17:09:13.682 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because erro         r when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/: c         ould not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/msp/pee         r/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/signcerts: no such file or directory

Comment: Heres the second error from $ docker logs orderer.example.com: 2018-07-02 17:09:12.027 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 007 Reading dire         ctory /etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp/signcerts
2018-07-02 17:09:12.027 UTC [orderer/common/server] initializeLocalMsp -> CRIT 0         08 Failed to initialize local MSP: could not load a valid signer certificate fro         m directory /etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/ms         p/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory

Comment: I saw the issue with your crypto directory, let try re-create using generate.sh. Note that in docker-compose.yml, FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/{privatekey} same in crypto-config/.../ca/{privatekey}

Comment: Btw, I would say you consider to checkout fabric release 1.1. It worked successfully for me!

Comment: I dont understand why the /etc/hyperledger/... folder is not in my VM. When I try generate.sh I get another issue. Here it is:  $ ./generate.sh
org1.example.com
...
2018-07-03 11:52:21.878 MST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
2018-07-03 11:52:21.879 MST [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 003 Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: unknown anchor 'OrdererDefaults' referenced
...
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...

btw - I have tried with fabric-samples 1.1. I tried fabric 1.1. and 1.2 now. Same issue.

Comment: in the docker-compose.yml, revise the volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/peer/crypto/
It will mouth the folder in your machine to containers.

Comment: Thanks Nhat Duy. I think that the paths for the chaincode and crypto volume mounts are OK (I also checked several others listed in docker-compose.yml) , they match my path well. However, I dont know what /var/run/ should be revised to. What path is /var/run/ pointing to normally, I guess something like C:/Program Files/?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that the location `/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/signcerts` is not accessible. For some reason it seems Docker Toolbox looks for this location under the home directory. So, check the home directory in the Docker VM using 
`echo $HOME` (in my case it is `C:/Users/knwny`) and then place the fabric-samples folder in that location.
This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Please properly format your answer, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks knwny. I moved fabric-samples to the home location as per your suggestion, but unfortunately I still have the same issue. I could not find this path inside the VM's /etc directory. Do I need to create the directory structure in the VM manually?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by re-running through the fabric installation guidelines: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html

The following procedure was entirely performed in a windows account with admin rights

Initial steps:

- Set the GOPATH environment variable
- Checked that Go is building executables correctly

All next steps in powershell in Admin mode

- Ran npm install npm@5.6.0 -g
- sudo apt-get install python (note that for me This command failed, but had python anyway and it seemed to work OK as it couldn't find sudo)
- Checked that python 2.7 is installed correctly
- Set git config --global core.autocrlf false
- Set git config --global core.longpaths true
- Ran npm install --global windows-build-tools
- Ran npm install --global grpc

Ran the following in Git Bash because cURL didnt work in powershell:

- curl -sSL http:/ /bit.ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s 1.2.0

Note that for the above command to work successfully I needed to have Docker running in a shell, i.e. running the Docker Toolbox installed start.sh script (I ran in Git Bash and worked OK).

Finally, in registerUser.js and enrollAdmin.js changed the local host, to be the IP address stated on docker on startup.

```
fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:7054', null , '', crypto_suite);
```

After doing this I re-ran the Fabric-samples 1) first-network and 2) fabcar examples and they worked as expected!! I think that I had missed out the GoPath and hadn't successfully installed the cURL command first time I tried.

Thanks to Nhat Duy and knwny for your help to resolve this issue.